# I get an error: Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, mysql, textbox

I've searched other errors like this but I did not found any solution.

```
public string[] vector;

//...

string comanda = "select * from chat";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conexiune);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(comanda, con);
MySqlDataReader dr;
int i = 1;
con.Open();
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    if (dr[1].ToString().Length > 1)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString() + ": " + dr[1].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\r\n";
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + dr[0].ToString() + ": " + dr[1].ToString();
        }
    }
    vector[i] = dr[1].ToString();
    i++; // Exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occured in Chat_1.exe   
}
con.Close();
timer1.Start();
```

Comment: Where is your `vector` code? Please show some more code here instead.

Comment: The vector is initialized here: http://i.imgur.com/kDRnf6a.png

Comment: Please post code - not screenshots.  Screenshots tend to get lost and are not searchable.

Comment: `vector` is not initialized there. It is defined there. Where do you do `vector = new string[x]` (where x is your intended size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please initialize your vector. It's null without using new with array.
Change your code to `public string[] vector = new String[3]`. Please replace 3 with the size you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the array. Try to initialize it somewhere, for example the method or better in the constructor:

```
vector = new string[number of how much elements you need];
```

While a list has a default length of 4 and the ability to resize itself, an array have either be given the number of their elements or come with predefined elements.

```
var vector = new string[] { "El 1", "El 2"...};
```